# Calculus Limits Help!!

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

[image]

How does the denominator switch from negative to positive?

Comment: It's a typo. Both the numerator and denominator should have had $+$ instead

Comment: Easier way: set $\sqrt{3x-2}=y$

Comment: So Im supposed to multiple the numerator and enominator by the conjugate right?

Comment: @chris Exactly.

Comment: Strictly speaking, every equation in that sequence of equations is _true,_ but writing the second line the way it was is quite pointless and misleading. The easiest way from the second line to the third is to go back to the first line and then do the desired multiplication by the conjugate the way it should be done in the first place.

Comment: I think you have got a lot of **acceptable** answers. I don't know your reason behind not **accepting** any of the $5$ below! Please don't leave answers unaccepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake was on the numerator and denominator. The author meant to multiply by the conjugate:

$$\frac{x-\sqrt{3x-2}}{x^2-4}=\frac{x-\sqrt{3x-2}}{x^2-4}\cdot\frac{x+\sqrt{3x-2}}{x+\sqrt{3x-2}}=\frac{x^2-(3x-2)^2}{(x^2-4)(x+\sqrt{3x-2})}$$

Answer (score 4):

The typo is in the second step.

It should be $x\color{red}{+}\sqrt{3x-2}$ instead of $x\color{red}{-}\sqrt{3x-2}$ in both the numerator and denominator.

The $3$rd step is fine.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typo, one rather has
$$
\frac{x-\sqrt{3x-2}}{x^2-4}=\frac{(x-\sqrt{3x-2})(x\color{red}{+}\sqrt{3x-2})}{(x^2-4)(x\color{red}{+}\sqrt{3x-2})}
$$ then it continues the right way.

Answer (score 1):

The second line has a typo.  They intended to multiply top and bottom by $x + \sqrt{3x-2}$, not $x - \sqrt{3x-2}$.  That's the way to get rid of the radical on top.

Answer (score 1):

It is a typo, but not where you have pointed. It should be
$$\lim_{x\to2}\frac{x-\sqrt{3x-2}}{x^2-4}=\lim_{x\to2}\frac{(x-\sqrt{3x-2})(x+\sqrt{3x-2})}{(x^2-4)(x+\sqrt{3x-2})}=\cdots$$